# Creating <input> with type="image" which redirects to another aspx page with arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

Thanks to all of the help stackoverflow has been, I'm a new programmer and this site has been probably the best resource!

I'm using vb.net to dynamically make a datatable, which is bound to a gridview and populated into a placeholder on my aspx page.  I would like each cell to have an image with an onclick method, which passes a session variable to the next aspx page.  I've tried making an input statement, where my DataRows are set individually like this:

```
DataRow(0) = "<input type='image' src='img.jpg' runat='server' onclick='NavigateToPage(NextPage.aspx)'>"
```

In my Chrome debug it is telling me my function is not within the scope that I'm calling it, so I tried making a javascript function on my .aspx page like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function NavigateToPage(page) {
    window.location.href = (page);
}
```

But still no redirect!  Thanks in advance for the replies during the holiday season.

Comment: NextPage.aspx is a string, it needs to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Also, if you redirect with JavaScript, you cannot put an object in the Session because this can only happen on the server. Thus, you should either let the image button POST the page and then redirect from the server, or use querystrings.

Comment: Are you setting it inside a form? Why not using img tag? Beware, clicking an input type image submit the form if nested inside any. I'm not ASP guy but isn't it your issue: `runat='server`?!

Answer (score 1):

Create a var for "page". Try putting it in the global scope. If you are worried about polluting the global, then namespace your function and put the var in your function. Also put your page string in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I modified the code a bit with your suggestions and I'm still having trouble.

    DataRow(3) = "<input type='image' src='img.jpg' onclick='javascript: NavigateToPage(12345);'/>"

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var RecordID;
    function NavigateToPage(RecordID) {
          window.location.href = '/Page.aspx';
    }
</script>

Here I am not even using the passed RecordID (once "page") variable, I just want to see it go to the next aspx page

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I figured out how to set it up with a querystring:

```
DataRow(0) = "<A href='NextPage.aspx'/><IMG src='img.jpg' Border=0>"
```

And of course put arguments for the NextPage using an href like this:

```
href='Nextpage.aspx?value1='1'&value2='2'&value3='3'
```

i forgot to add initially that I have a small function at the end that decodes the text string into an html element after the table is bound to the gridview:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
        For ColNo As Integer = 3 To 6
            gv.Rows(i).Cells(ColNo).Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(gv.Rows(i).Cells(ColNo).Text)
        Next
    Next
```